# How does one validate the format of a date in XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to verify that a date is in the correct format in some XML e.g.

```
<Student>
<Name>Test</Name>
<DOB>14121992</DOB>
</Student>
```

I need to check whether the DOB is in the date format `YYMMDD` using XSLT? Is there any function for doing this? I have seen a lot of code that only converts the date/time, not validating it.

Is it possible do this validation using a schema?

Comment: Both schema and XSLT 2.0 can check against the `xs:date` type which has a format `YYYY-MM-DD`. As you have a different format you would need to try to construct an `xs:date` from the components of your input data and then do `$var castable as xs:date` in XSLT 2.0. More checks might be needed to ensure there is no additional data in the XML, as for instance in your sample you have a lot of digits.

Comment: XSLT isn't really concerned with validation (although a schema aware processor could be used to cause a failure if the document doesn't validate).  As stated in the other comment, XML Schema language can be used to validate that, as can Relax NG (with a datatypes module), or Schematron.  You could also write a template that would output a message using `<xsl:message>` in the case of a date that doesn't match the format - but you'd have to be watching for messages.